# How to write unit test for Entity in TypeORM?

Tags: typeorm

I'm from `Ruby On Rails` world, so I always write a test for models, but I'm not sure how can I do that in TypeORM with Mocha + Chai + Sinon ?

My model file
`User.ts`

```
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, OneToMany } from "typeorm";
import { IsNotEmpty } from "class-validator";
import { Post } from "./Post";

@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({
    unsigned: true
  })
  id: number;

  @Column({ unique: true })
  @IsNotEmpty()
  name: string;

  @OneToMany(type => Post, post => post.user)
  posts: Post[];
}
```

I would like to write unit test for my model file, like `User.spec.ts`

```
describe("User", () => {
  let result: any;
  before(TestContext.create);
  after(TestContext.reset);

  it("should have many posts", () => {});
  it("name should be unique", () => {});
  it("name should not be empty", () => {});
});
```

Any advice is welcome!